# What is the meaning of "Invalid Argument" and what causes this error when debugging JavaScript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, debugging, arguments

I am getting the error when using `getElementById()`. I won't post the entire program since it's a homework assignment, but when I comment out this line of code I don't get any more syntax errors. What should I be looking for in the rest of the code that could have caused the problem?

```
document.getElementById("bugOne").style.left = xPos + "px";
```

Also- what is an "Invalid Argument" error usually caused by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Invalid Argument"` is going to be a runtime error, not a syntax error.  Don't jump to `getElementById()` as the culprit - you have a lot going on in one line of code.  For debugging, it's useful to break up complex statements:

```
var bugOne = document.getElementById("bugOne");
var left = xPos + "px";
bugOne.style.left = left;
```

In IE8, if you set a bad value on a style property, you get an `"Invalid argument"` error.  I'm guessing `xPos` contains either `undefined` or `NaN`.  Set a breakpoint in your debugger and examine the value of `xPos`.

Comment: You're right. xPos is undefined so that must have caused the problem.

Comment: Although testing in IE8 is good practice - it's still very common in total visitors to your average website. I make a specific habit of not upgrading IE so I'm still stuck in the same past my visitors are (then use Chrome for any non-test browsing).

Comment: @chris - The IE dev tools allow you to view pages in different browser modes. So, you can test IE8 from within IE10. There's really no reason not to upgrade.

Comment: @gilly3 Start up a WinXP VM and compare the same page in real IE8 and the tools. You'll get tool-specific bugs and actual IE8-specific bugs. The IE dev tools are bunk.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the the code (HTML and JS) for xPos variable and for bugOne, from definition to usage, as that might make your question easier to answer.

Also, are you using jQuery? If not, why not?

[This page](http://www.overset.com/2008/03/05/javascript-invalid-argument-errors/) (linked) doesn't explain what "invalid argument" means, but it shows areas where it most likely occurs.

Comment: No, I don't know what jQuery is.

Comment: It's a homework assignment, probably not supposed to be using jQuery.

Comment: It's probably fine to use that. The instructor lets people use dreamweaver (but I don't have that). I'll look into that.

Comment: @jfriend00 [sarcasm]When I was at varsity, doing more than I had to in order to make my code simpler didn't count against me. I would be sad to learn that not every institution encourages thinking outside the box, even on homework assignments.[/sarcasm] I wish I had known of (and used) jQuery in my varsity Web Dev classes as my core JS knowledge is _still_ very shaky. If your point is that learning jQuery would take too long for a(n) HW assignment (presumably due soon), I concede the point.


[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a cross-browser JS lib used in the Pro Web Development **real world**.

Comment: If you're interested in saving yourself a lot of hair-pulling and swearing, I recommend Pakt Pub's "Learning jQuery" (http://www.packtpub.com/jQuery/book). As I'm not sure of the SO policy on piracy/ linking to _pirated_ content, I'm not going to offer you torrent links or condone free sharing of valuable information ; find them/ this yourself. (Links do exist).

Comment: @NigelNquande - many homework assignments have very specific rules about using third party code from outside the browser.  If one did not get specific permission to use jQuery and jQuery wasn't part of the class, then it would not be safe to assume it's allowed or in the intended spirit of the homework assignment.  My son is a freshman in college and 11 kids in his programming class got a serious reprimand (automatic grade demotion in the class) for using code they found on the internet in a homework assignment.